# What will be the input_shape of tf.keras.layers.Conv3D be for these inputs

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, convolutional-neural-network, convolution

I have many videos, and each video is made up of 37 images (there are 37 frames in the whole video). And the dimension of each image is `(100, 100, 3)`.... So the shape of my dataset is `[num_of_videos, 37, 100, 100, 3]`

If I want to pass these videos thorugh the `tf.keras.layers.Conv3D()`... what will be the input shape for the conv3D be:

```
Conv3D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=[What will the input shape here be])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Keras document,

> **Input shape**
>
> *5+D tensor with shape: batch_shape + (**channels, conv_dim1, conv_dim2, conv_dim3**) if data_format='channels_first' or 5+D tensor with shape: batch_shape + (conv_dim1, conv_dim2, conv_dim3, channels) if data_format='channels_last'*

Assuming `data_format='channels_last'` and *num_of_videos* may be used to decide *batch_size*(*which is not required while defing input_shape)*,

`input_shape=[ 100, 100, 37, 3 ]`